# RDLC Report Viewer Drill Through Report

Tags: asp.net, rdlc, reportviewer2008

I had posted this question on MSDN Forum

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsreportcontrols/thread/f00e3406-354d-4f54-acce-7b7f0ad4c90f

But I am not getting any response. Can you please help me. I am really stuck with this rather simple task.

My code seems to be correct but still I get the

A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'DataSet1_Order_Details'.

Sorry for the cross post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the error.

I was adding the data source like

```
this.ReportViewer.Localreport.DataSource.Add
(new RemoteDataSource("DataSet1_Order_Details", ObjectDataSource2.ID));
```

instead the data source should be added in the following manner

```
DataSet1TableAdapter.OrderDetails od = new DataSet1TableAdapter.OrderDetails();
((LocalReport)e.report).Datasources.Add(new RemoteDataSource("DataSet1_Order_Details", od.get(orderid))
```

this resolved the issue and now I am able to have drill down in the ReortViewer report.

Regards,
Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

I had a same experience and it was because I try tosee the report from a wrong place, let me explain

- There is a dataSet in RDLC reports
- There is a method in DAL which get data from db
- There is a Method in BAL or UI which call the DAL method and fill dataset. Most of time this is a unique page which get some parameter from user and fill dataset and finally redirect user to the report viewer page.
- your eror appears in report viewer page

So the following may happened

- you enter directly to reportviewer page without filling dataset
- you went to correct page and fill the dataset but inreport viewer pageyoudidn't bind your dataset to your report in code behind.
- in some cases it can be because of session expiration.

Comment: I have not entered the report viewer without populating the dataset.

my first report appears perfectly. when I click on the link, I have the drill through event handler where I make every possible effort to populate the dataset. have a look at the code which I have posted and also the screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, too, though the real key was right here:

```
((LocalReport)e.report)
```

In my case, I am using:

```
((LocalReport)e.report).LoadReportDefinition(report_stream);

foreach (ReportParameter rp in ((LocalReport)e.report).OriginalParametersToDrillthrough)
        {
            _paramCollection[rp.Name].parameterValue.AddRange(rp.Values.OfType<string>());
        }
DataTable newData = GetData();
ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
rds.Name = _datasetName;
rds.Value = newData;
((LocalReport)e.report).DataSources.Add(rds);
```

The reportviewer handles the rest. @Knows Not Much, thanks for the lead.